# Stored procedure returning incorrect value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to calculate percentage of attendance with the below stored proc, but it is returning incorrect values. Can anyone help me spot the error in my sp plz.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[percentage]
@stdid int,
@strtdate date,
@enddate date
AS
BEGIN
Select [std_status], 
((select Count(std_status) where (std_status='P')) * 100 / 
(Select Count(*) From [DB].[dbo].[attendance] where admission_Id_int=@stdid and    
(entry_date BETWEEN @strtdate and @enddate))) 
as attendencepercentage
From [DB].[dbo].[attendance]
where std_status='P' and admission_Id_int=@stdid
Group By std_status
END
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the data you are using, what you're getting, and what you expect to get.

Comment: i got incorrect percentage.. its above hundred..like 133 and 200

Comment: So you want a value below one hundred? subtract 100? divide by 100? replace with 1? You'll need to be more specific about what you actually want.

Comment: no of days a student present in class*100 nd then divide by total no of days in a month.. at start i got correct result.. but when i added parameter for start and end date and "between" then got incorrect result..

Answer (score 0):

I can't make much sense of your query. So lets start with this one.

Below I have bunch of terms. You need to identify which ones are the numerator and denominator for your percentage. I can't work it out from your query.

```
select
sum(case when std_status='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Term1,
sum(case when admission_Id_int=@stdid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Term2,
sum(case when std_status='P' and admission_Id_int=@stdid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Term3,
sum(case when std_status='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
sum(case when admission_Id_int=@stdid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SampleDivisionOfTerm1AndTerm2
From [DB].[dbo].[attendance]
where entry_date BETWEEN @strtdate and @enddate
Group By std_status
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your query can return incorrect percentage is because the count of `'P'` rows does not include a filter on `entry_date`, whereas the other count does. It means that for a fairly small range specified by `@strtdate` and `@enddate` the first count can exceed the second one and the result of the division can thus become greater than 100%.

So, perhaps one simple solution to this problem would be just to repeat the `entry_date` filter in the main WHERE clause:

```
Select [std_status], 
((select Count(std_status) where (std_status='P')) * 100 / 
(Select Count(*) From [DB].[dbo].[attendance] where admission_Id_int=@stdid and 
(entry_date BETWEEN @strtdate and @enddate))) 
as attendencepercentage
From [DB].[dbo].[attendance]
where std_status='P' and admission_Id_int=@stdid
  and (entry_date BETWEEN @strtdate and @enddate)
Group By std_status
```

However, as written, such query would be needlessly complicated. For example, this subquery

```
(select Count(std_status) where (std_status='P'))
```

is perfectly redundant and could be re-written as simply

```
COUNT(*)
```

because the main WHERE clause already has the `std_status='P'` filter. But you could actually rewrite the entire query in such a way as to avoid *any* subquery. Here is one example:

```
SELECT
  std_status = 'P',
  AttendancePercentage = COUNT(CASE std_status WHEN 'P' THEN 1 END) * 100 / COUNT(*)
FROM
  [DB].[dbo].[attendance]
WHERE
  admission_Id_int = @stdid
  AND entry_date BETWEEN @strtdate and @enddate
;
```

The above query retrieves all rows matching the specified parameters regardless of `std_status`, counts separately all the rows (`COUNT(*)`) and those matching the `'P'` status (`COUNT(CASE std_status WHEN 'P' THEN 1 END)`) and uses the results to calculate `AttendancePercentage`.

Note also the absence of `GROUP BY std_status` in the rewrite. It is not needed there because one of the counts disregards `std_status` completely and the other uses the column differently.

I am not sure if you really need the `std_status` column in the output, but in case you do and it must show the status for which the percentage is calculated, I added it as a calculated column with a hardcoded value. Otherwise the column seems redundant there and could easily be removed.

Comment: it works but when i want to retrieve this procedure in crystal report it gives me error (ado error code 0x80040e14: divide by zero error)                                                        create procedure [dbo].[DMC1]
@stdentid int
as begin
select
std_status='p',
attendancepercentage= (COUNT (case std_status when 'p' then 1 end) * 100/COUNT(*))
from
[DB].[dbo].[attendance] 
where admission_Id_int=@stdentid
end

Comment: @khcula: Apparently it happens when there are no matches (in which case COUNT(*) is 0). You should decide what you want to return in such cases. One workaround is to replace `COUNT(*)` with `NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0)` - that way `AttendancePercentage` will be NULL when there are no matches.